# Roles Based Security for EJB deployed on Weblogic

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I am working on an EJB application. I have to apply role based security on session bean(EJB3) methods, for which I tried annotating the session bean method with "@RolesAllowed" as below,

For creating User, groups and roles i am using jazn-data.xml as below,

After the deploying the EJB and running the application, security does get applied and throws an exception [EJB:010160]Security Violation: User: 'XXX' has insufficient permission to access EJB

After Adding the weblogic ejb deployment descriptor as below,

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.1/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd"
                  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar">
    <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <ejb-name>ApplicationFacade</ejb-name>
        <stateless-session-descriptor/>
        <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
    </weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>PVUser</role-name>
        <principal-name>pv</principal-name>
    </security-role-assignment>
    <security-role-assignment>
        <role-name>PRUser</role-name>
        <principal-name>pr</principal-name>

    </security-role-assignment>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

It starts working as expected.

My question is related to weblogic ejb deployment descriptor(weblogic-ejb-jar.xml), do I have to make an entry for each user (pricipal-name), each time I am adding a new user or is there a way by which i can map a user-groups?

Also let me know if I have missed any other configuration required to add permissions.

Comment: You can also configure the roles at the realm and configure weblogic with: <security-role-assignment>
  <role-name>RoleName</role-name>
  <externally-defined />
 </security-role-assignment>

Answer (score 1):

The Answer is yes,

- and what you need to do is creating a group named xxx by login to the
  weblogic console( modify within the Security Realms panel)
- then adding all of the user to the group named xxx
- lastly in the weblogic ejb deployment descriptor you just need to
  specify the group name as

> < principal-name >xxxgroup name < / principal-name >

- as a result, every member within the group would share the
  permission.